# Reading metadata from build.gradle

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

According to [this](https://developer.android.com/tools/building/configuring-gradle.html#workBuildVariants) I can create several "flavors" in my Android Studio project. But, it looks like I can only create two trees that then will be built.

Is it possible to add variables in my `build.gradle` file, that I can then access from code, so that I can have a more fine-grained control on how my app will be built?

E.g. in my `build.gradle`:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.example.app.free"
        showAds "yes"
    }
    full {
        applicationId "com.example.app.full"
        showAds "no"
    }
}
```

and then in my code

```
String showAds = Gradle.getString("showAds");
if ("yes".equals(showAds)) {
     // show ads
}
```

Comment: `buildConfigField "boolean", "showAds", "true" `, and then `BuildConfig.showAds`, should do the trick. And you can redefine it in each flavor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to add variables in my gradle.build file, that I can then access from code, so that I can have a more fine-grained control on how my app will be built?

I presume you really mean your `build.gradle` file.

For your specific case, you could just use the already-existing `BuildConfig.FLAVOR`, which will be `free` or `paid`.

Or, you can use `buildConfigField` to add your own fields to `BuildConfig`:

```
productFlavors {
    free {
        applicationId "com.example.app.free"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "I_CAN_HAZ_ADS", 'true'
    }
    full {
        applicationId "com.example.app.full"
        buildConfigField "boolean", "I_CAN_HAZ_ADS", 'false'
    }
}
```

Then, you would refer to `BuildConfig.I_CAN_HAZ_ADS` in your Java code.

Note that I have only used `BuildConfig` field for `String` types, not `boolean`. AFAIK, any simple type like this should work.

Comment: I do find the `BuildConfig.FLAVOR`, but the added ones are not available. I get a "Cannot resolve symbol buildConfigField" in the `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @BartFriederichs Did you synchronize with gradle after making changes in script ? Also check if you define the variable correctly.

Comment: @TheLittleNaruto I guess that was it. I seem to have it all working now.

Comment: Cool :-) You must accept this as answer so that anyone can get help.